# Problems charging a card with Stripe in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, stripe-payments

I'm building a Rails app that takes credit cards and I'm trying to use Stripe to do it. I'm having some issues passing the data from my app to Stripe in order to charge. That's what I'm hoping to get help with on this topic.

First, I have a standard form (with values instead of placeholders for quick submitting for testing purposes). The form successfully enters the name and email into the DB and the customer's "plan" is hardcoded in the controller for the time being:

```
    <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
      <div class="payment-errors"></div>
      <div class="name field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :value => "Your name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="email field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :value => "yourname@example.com" %>
      </div>
      <div class="cc_number field">
        <%= label_tag 'cc_number' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'cc_number', nil, :value => "4242424242424242" %>
      </div>
      <div class="ccv field">
        <%= label_tag 'ccv' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'ccv', nil, :value => "123" %>
      </div>
      <div class="cc_expiration field">
        <%= label_tag 'cc_month', "Expiration date" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'cc_month', nil, :value => "12" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'cc_year', nil, :value => "2012" %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Continue", :class => 'btn' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Also in my `signups_view` where the above code is, I have this JS, [mostly provided by Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // this identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE['public'] %>');

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
      if (response.error) {
          // show the errors on the form
          $(".payment-errors").text(response.error.message);
          $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
          var form$ = $("form");
          // token contains id, last4, and card type
          var token = response['id'];
          // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='customer[stripe_token]' id='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
          // and submit
          $('.cc_number.field, .ccv.field, .cc_expiration.field').remove();
          form$.get(0).submit();
      }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
      // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");

      Stripe.createToken({
          number: $('#cc_number').val(),
          cvc: $('#ccv').val(),
          exp_month: $('#cc_month').val(),
          exp_year: $('#cc_year').val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

There seems to be a problem with the line `form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='customer[stripe_token]' id='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");`, as my Ruby app breaks when it gets to `customer[stripe_token]`.

```
Finally, in my `customers_controller`, I have:

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    @customer.product = 

    if @customer.save
      save_order
      redirect_to @customer
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end

  def save_order
    Stripe.api_key = STRIPE['secret']
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 20,
      :currency => "usd",
      :card => @customer.stripe_token,
      :description => "Product 1"
    )
  end
```

Whenever I submit the form, it hits the `else` clause in the controller each time and after plenty of debugging, Googling around and stripping out this from and rebuilding from scratch, I'm still stumped.

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Edit: Added the `customer model`

```
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :stripe_token, :product

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex },
                    :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 60 },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :name, :length => {:minimum => 2, :maximum => 80 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your Customer model to get an idea of what's going on. If @customer.save returns false, it means that a validator is likely failing.

Also, do you have stripe_token as an accessible attribute on your model? Otherwise you won't be able to assign it form the form like you're doing. Note that the token should **not** be stored in the database, since it can only be used once.

```
class Customer 
  attr_accessor :stripe_token # do you have this?
end
```

One more note: you will probably want to store a Stripe ID field so that you can retrieve customer payments and cancel their account later.

Comment: I do have :stripe_token as an accessible attribute. Adding the customer model to the original post now

Comment: attr_accessible suggests that it's stored in the database, which it really shouldn't be. attr_accessor will create a getter/setter so that you can temporarily store it in the instance, which is the intended behavior here. At any rate, can you print the result of @customer.errors.full_messages.inspect after the save fails?